# Why do I get a page content instead of a redirect?

Tags: 8

I have to send a request to an external API which returns a redirection link, using the following code.

```php
try {
  $response = \Drupal::httpClient()->get($url, ['headers' => ['Accept' => 'text/html']]);
  $data = (string) $response->getBody();
  if (empty($data)) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  else{
    return $data;
  }
} catch (RequestException $e) {
  return FALSE;
}
```

What I get in `$data` is the following content.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" class="h-100">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="asdsad">
  <!-- CSRF Token -->
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="aaaaa1231231">
  <title>TEST</title>
  <link rel="canonical" href="tamal.com">
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="http:xyz.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Why do I get a page content instead of a redirect?

Answer (score 0):

this actually because of the second argument **['headers' => ['Accept' => 'text/html']** it tells the server to serve a plain text instead of html so your browser will end up print the text instead of parsing it as HTML,so just remove the second argument **['headers' => ['Accept' => 'text/html']**

so you code will become like this one :

Code :

```
$url = 'xyz';

try {
  $response = \Drupal::httpClient()->get($url);
  $data = (string) $response->getBody();
  if (empty($data)) {
    return FALSE;
  }else{
    return $data;
  }
} catch (RequestException $e) {
  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: No, *text/html* is the MIME type for HTML; the one for plain text is *text/plain*.